# How to run Python with FastAPI on IIS 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iis, fastapi, iis-10

Configuration:

- Windows Server 2019
- installed httpPlatformHandler x64 from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler
- installed Python 3.12.1 32-bit in C:\python312-32\ for all users
- installed FastAPI library using
- created new app pool (Pool-A) with a custom account (User-A) as identity, no managed code, integrated pipeline
- created C:\python-logs\ folder for logs
- created C:\python-app\ with file main.py
- set full control for User-A in folders: python312-32, python-logs, python-app
- added application to route /python-app with Pool-A

C:\python-app\main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Sample app"}
```

C:\python-app\web.config (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="c:\python312-32\python.exe"
                  arguments="c:\python-app\main.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="c:\python-app\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I always get:

- HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
- Error Code 0x80070003
- Config Error Cannot read configuration file

What is wrong?

I didn't use FastCGI because the project is not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I have included below instruction to use FastAPI (Python library) in IIS with HTTP Platform Handler.

1. Install Python 3.12 64-bit for all users ([installer](https://www.python.org/))
2. Install Microsoft HTTP Platform Handler 1.2 ([installer](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler))
3. Install Python packages as administrator `pip install fastapi uvicorn`
4. Create folder `C:\python-app`
5. Create folder `C:\python-app\logs`
6. Create `C:\python-app\main.py`

   ```py
   from fastapi import FastAPI
   app = FastAPI()
   @app.get("/python") #route must contain alias set in IIS
   async def get_root():
       return {"message": "Hello World"}
   ```
7. Create "C:\python-app\web.config"

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
           <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
       </handlers>
       <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\uvicorn.exe" arguments="main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% --log-level info" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\uvicorn" startupTimeLimit="60" processesPerApplication="16">
       <environmentVariables>
           <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\python-app\" />
           <environmentVariable name="HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
       </environmentVariables>
       </httpPlatform>
   </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
8. Create `PythonAppPool`

   - no managed code
   - integrated pipeline
   - "ApplicationPoolIdentity" as Application Pool Identity
9. Add permissions to folders

   ```
   icacls "C:\Program Files\Python312" /grant "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
   icacls "C:\Program Files\Python312" /grant "Builtin\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
   icacls "C:\python-app" /grant "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
   icacls "C:\python-app" /grant "Builtin\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
   ```
10. add python application to IIS on the host's root

    - alias: python
    - application pool: PythonAppPool
    - Physical path: C:\python-app
11. Open `http:\\localhost\python` in browser
12. If everything is working then you can change `--log-level` to `error` in `web.config` file

Comment: From minimal permission principle, I think some of the `IUSR` permissions you granted might not be needed. BTW, you might accept your own answer to close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a lack of permission or by a physical path that doesn't match the path for the virtual directory. For example, no Web.config exists under the web app physical root path.

Verify that the Web.config path exists and has correct permissions set.
Collect Process Monitor logs to get more information about the error.

More information you can refer to this link: [HRESULT code 0x80070003](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x80070003).