# How to run FastAPI in IIS10 with websocket enabled?

Tags: iis, websocket, fastapi

I follow the steps below:
[How to run Python with FastAPI on IIS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627264/how-to-run-python-with-fastapi-on-iis-10)

Now I can run FastAPI in IIS10, but without websocket.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Public-T\Python\VenvFastapi\Scripts\uvicorn.exe"
                  arguments="main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile="D:\WebSite\FastApi\logs\uvicorn"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\WebSite\FastApi\" />
        <environmentVariable name="HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the websocket code, it's OK if running standalone.

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

But in IIS, I always get "WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state." on the client side.

Comment: You might find the referenced links in my blog post useful (or not very), https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#flask-with-socketio The Python WebSocket implementation requires special steps.

Comment: I think you have ouccured the same issue as this thread, please check if this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71542183/websocket-getting-closed-immediately-after-connecting-to-fastapi-endpoint